# What's wrong with this try catch code (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, compilation, try-catch

Been 2 hours I'm trying to compile my code, doesn't seem to work...
Check out which line gives me a msg in the code has a comment.

Does the Try and catch isolate the scoop of a variable?

```
import java.io.*;
public class Tp3Partie2 {

    public static void main (String[] params) {
        int cmd;
        FileReader fEntree;
        FileReader fEntree2;
        BufferedReader entree;
        Cars [] tableau;
        try {
            fEntree = new FileReader( "test.txt" );
            fEntree2 = new FileReader( "test.txt" );
            LineNumberReader nbrLigne = new LineNumberReader( fEntree );
            nbrLigne.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int nbrLigneFichier = nbrLigne.getLineNumber();
            nbrLigneFichier = nbrLigneFichier + 1;
            entree = new BufferedReader( fEntree2 );
            tableau = new Cars[nbrLigneFichier/5];
            System.out.println( tableau.length );
            for(int i=0;i<nbrLigneFichier/5;i++) {
                String type = entree.readLine();
                type.trim();
                int posType = Cars.obtenirCode(type, 't');

                String couleur = entree.readLine();
                couleur.trim();
                int posCouleur = Cars.obtenirCode(couleur, 'c');

                int pointure = Integer.parseInt(entree.readLine());
                double prix = Double.parseDouble(entree.readLine());
                boolean neuf = Boolean.parseBoolean(entree.readLine());
                System.out.println(i);
                tableau[i] = new Cars(posType,posCouleur,pointure,prix,neuf);
                tableau[i].toString();
            }
            entree.close();
            nbrLigne.close();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            System.out.println( MessagesTp3.FICHIER_EXISTE_PAS );
        }

        do {            
            System.out.println( MessagesTp3.AJOUTER_PAIRE );
            System.out.println( MessagesTp3.SUPPRIMER_PAIRE );
            System.out.println( MessagesTp3.AFFICHER_PAIRES );
            System.out.println( MessagesTp3.QUITTER  );
            System.out.println( MessagesTp3.VOTRE_CHOIX ); 
            cmd = Clavier.lireInt();

            switch (cmd) {
                case 1:
                break;
                case 2:
                break;
                case 3:
                System.out.println( MessagesTp3.LISTE_CHAUSSURES );                
                for(int i=0;i<tableau.length;i++) { // This line gives me a msg of "variable tableau might not been initialized"
                    tableau[i].toString();
                }        
                break;
                case 9:
                break;
                default:
                System.out.println( MessagesTp3.CHOIX_NONVALIDE );
                break;
            }

        } while ( !(cmd == 9) );

        System.out.println( MessagesTp3.FIN_PROGRAMME );
    } // main

    public static void enregistrerPaires () {
    }

    public static void ajouterPaires () {
    }

    public static void suprimerPaires () {
    }
}
```

Comment: you should provide the error details

Comment: It gives me a "variable tableau might not have been initialized" in the switch .... il'l edit my post so it can be more clear.

Comment: I can't edit my original post ... but the error's occurs after the "System.out.println( MessagesTp3.LISTE_CHAUSSURES );" line ...

Comment: I noticed that the try/catch structure influence's the scope of the array. How can it work without beeing blocked by the try/catch ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually try and catch does not limit the scope, but what the compiler is saying is that there might have been an exception thrown *before* initializing the variable inside the try catch block.

In that case the exception is thrown and caught, the variable is not initialized and then the code would continue. But further on, we get to the line with compilation error, where the variable would not have been initialized.

The compiler detects this possibility and throws an error, the solution is for example to initialise the variable with the empty array:

```
Cars [] tableau = {};
```

Comment: But the array is suposse to be initialized after reading my tet.txt file it stores some data into it !

Comment: that is right, but imagine the file does not exist or was moved. then an exception is thrown before tableau is filled in, and the exception gets caught. the program resumes after the catch, there would be no value to the variable reaching the error line. no value at all, not even null or empty array, the variable would be completely uninitialized. this is the problem that the compiler is reporting and preventing

Comment: Well if i declare and initialize my array in the try catch it gives me a "Cannot find symbol - variable tableau" message.

Comment: I noticed that the try/catch structure influence's the scope of the array. How can it work without beeing blocked by the try/catch ?